# Fail2ban on centos 7 does not add rule to firewall. Firewall-cmd used on system

Tags: fail2ban, centos7, firewalld

I installed the latest fail2ban from centos/epel I have added the ssh enabled option in jail.local.  I have tried with action and banaction = firewallcmd-ipset neither made any difference.  iptables-multi was originally in the config and I changed that after i noticed it wasnt banning. I have tried listing iptables rules as well as firewall-cmd --list-all-zones and nothing is listed.  also the ban log has a couple of already banned messages in it.
NOTICE  [sshd] 61.174.51.204 already banned

Answer (score 0):

If you check the action.d directory, you will find all firewalld-related actions forgot to put on `reload` command after adding the rule to DROP or REJECT the  source IPs by fail2ban, `reload` is important due to it makes the rules to be accepted by FirewallD.
I suggest you to modify the actions to fit what you need, however, IMHO, FirewallD acts like a manger to control iptables and it's more suitable for workstation than server environment.
Thus, the most efficient way to solve your problem is,

> systemctl stop firewalld
>
> systemctl mask firewalld

and enable your iptables.